# OpenUrl and itms-services with credentials

Tags: ios, objective-c, ota, openurl, custom-url

I want to install an app from inside another app. I know it is possible with the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=",self.plistURL]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

My problem is that that the .plist is located in an area on the server where the user has to enter user credentials to access it. So when I execute this code, the user is asked for the credentials in Safari. But I don't want that. I want the app to enter the credentials.

I already tried to open the custom url scheme with an AFNetworking operation but it seems that it can´t handle custom url schemes because I get the error:

`"Unsupported url"`

**So my question is:** is there any way to use itms-services with user credentials or is there a workaround?

I also considered that maybe downloading the plist and executing it from an internal url could solve the problem, but I wanted to make sure that there is no easier way.

Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time of experimenting I dont think it is possible to use itms-services with credentials. I ended up passing the credentials directly in the url with:

```
https://Username:Password@plisturl
```

In the plist I also added the credentials to the ipa URL. I don´t think it is a clean solution to add the credentials in clear text but it is the only solution I see at the moment.

Keep me updated if someone has a better solution.

Comment: Be aware, iOS8 might not support this. I can confirm that your solution works in iOS 4-7 though.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on iOS 8.1.3. First, Safari throws a Phishing Alert... Then you get a prompt "Unable to Download App" from iOS during install. It appears it works *enough* to get to the .plist, however, the asset URL, containing the UN/PW, seems to result in the failure.

Comment: Hi Travis. I tested the installation on an iPad3 with iOS 8.1.3 and the app still installs correctly with no issues. Have you verified your installation worked on previous iOS versions?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?  The use of a token might be a little more secure than clear text.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H255a9QacH06Z9-239xAOEixbR967RmLu7-o0siRaJg/edit?pli=1